# Grub isn't loading

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I recently got Ubuntu on my Intel i3 2.60GHz computer. I loved having Ubuntu as an option but I opened windows boot manager and now I can't get back to Ubuntu. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

(Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Comment: Consult the documentation for your motherboard to determine how to make changes to the boot priority

Comment: If UEFI boot, you should always be able to boot any install from UEFI boot menu, just as you booted live installer to install Ubuntu in first place. Both Windows updates & Ubuntu updates may reinstall boot loaders and then that install is moved to first in UEFI boot order. If you have BIOS install and one drive big hassle on temporarily installing boot loaders.  Note that grub only boots working Windows & Windows updates may turn fast start up back on, and then grub will not boot Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need to fix your grub. For this you have to open Ubuntu. You can use a **live Ubuntu** in this case.Then

- install **boot repair**

  - `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`
  - `sudo apt-get update`
  - `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`
- open boot repair app :

  - on termianl :  `boot-repair`
  - Select **Recommended repair**
  - ok for everything
- then restart pc and remove usb.

Hope you will find your both boot options.